# Proving an equation where f and g are differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\frac{d}{dx}ln(f(x)g(x)) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} + \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$$

Okay, so I'm not sure if it's this simple so correct me where needed:

$$\ln(f(x)g(x)) = \ln f(x) +\ln g(x)$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln f(x) + \frac{d}{dx}\ln g(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} + \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$$

Is it really that simple? I thought I would've had to applied the product rule but I'm unsure.

Comment: Well, it is actually so simple if $f$ and $g$ are positive. If $f$ and $g$ are negative then $\ln f,\ln g$ do not exist. But in such a case $\ln(f(x)g(x)) = \ln(-f(x)) + \ln(-g(x)).$

Comment: In the second equality, you need $f(x)>0$ and $g(x)>0$

Comment: So assuming these conditions are fulfilled, then the solution above is correcT?

Comment: @user382540 Yes, thats right!

Answer (score 0):

Since we can not directly separate $ln$ into 2 parts, we still need to use the chain rule and product rule, and we also know $f(x)g(x)>0$.
$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(f(x)g(x))=\frac{1}{f(x)g(x)}(f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x))$$
which can be simplified to be
$$=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}+\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}$$

Comment: Why can't you separate the log? As long as the argument is positive there is no problem. If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both negative, the product is positive and you can write $\ln(f(x)g(x)) = \ln(-f(x)) + \ln(-g(x))$ so you can simply write $\ln(f(x)g(x))= \ln(|f(x)|) + \ln(|g(x)|)$ whenever $f(x)g(x)>0$